# Ocaml stack overflow with easy computations

Tags: recursion, syntax, ocaml

Here is my code:

```
let rec sum n =  
    if n <= 0 then 0
    else if n / 2 * 2 = n then 3 * n + 50 * (sum n-2)
    else n + 10 * (sum n-1);;
```

The math problem is simply as following:

```
sn =
    0 if n = 0
    50*sn-2 + 3*n, if n > 0 and n is even
    10*sn-1 + n  , if n > 0 and n is odd
```

When I test `sum 5`, it popped out "stack overflow" error as following:

> Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: always check your recursion carefully: initialisation, stopping condition and recurse. Stack overflow during evaluation means that your stopping condition is wrong!

Answer (score 5):

That is because `n` is not being changed in the recursive call. You'll have to wrap the `n-1` and `n-2` in parenthesis. You're calling `(sum n)-1` instead of `sum (n-1)`.

Answer (score 5):

Add parentheses:

```
let rec sum n =  
    if n <= 0 then 0
    else if n / 2 * 2 = n then 3 * n + 50 * (sum (n-2))
    else n + 10 * (sum (n-1));;

(* prints 3125 *)
print_int (sum 5);;
```

Instead of calling `sum` on `n-2` (or `n-1`), you're calling it on `n` and subtracting `2` (or `1`) from the result. Since the input never changes, it recurses until it overflows the stack.